# Обобщающее слово

Tags: однородные-члены

Добрый день.

Уместно ли в данном предложении ставить обобщающее слово ( умение) перед зависимыми приложениями, или его нужно дублировать?

**Умения задавать каверзные вопросы, разговорить своего собеседника, принесли ему роль сильного игрока в медийном пространстве.**

С большим уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение немного отредактировано:

**Умение** (какое? )задавать каверзные вопросы, разговорить своего собеседника обеспечило ему славу сильного игрока в медийном пространстве.

Это однородные несогласованные определения, выраженные инфинитивом, в позиции после определяемого слова  "умение" (не обособляются).